Showing that a Mobius transformation sends the unit circle to a specific circle
I want to show that the Mobius transformation $z \mapsto \frac{1-z}{1-rz}$ where $r\in (0,1)$ sends the unit circle onto a circle symmetric with respect to the real axis and passing through $0$ and $2/(1+r)$.
Here's what I tried: I plugged in $z=e^{it}$ and got an expression which cannot be simplified further to get something of the form: $\frac{1+e^{it}}{1+r}$ which is something that I want.
Alternatively, I see that $z=1$ gets mapped to $z=0$ and $z=-1$ gets mapped to $z=2/(1+r)$ and Mobius transformation must map circles to circles (line is not possible in this case because $r\in (0,1)$) but I do not see how it is symmetric about $x$-axis.

The equation of unit circle is $|z|=1$. Substituting $z\mapsto \frac{1-z}{1-rz}$, we get $|z-1| = r|z-\frac1r|$. The points satisfying this equation define a circle (see Apollonius circle). Clearly, $z=0$ and $z=2/(1+r)$ are points on this circle. Moreover, since $1$ and $1/r$ are points on the real axis, the diameter of this circle is along the real axis, which means the circle is symmetric about the real axis. Alternatively, substituting $z\mapsto \bar z$ gives the same equation, so it is symmetric about the real axis.
